# how to make data not in json value 0?

Tags: php, json

I'm really sorry for my bad title because I don't know how to shorten my question.
I had a bit help earlier with the thing I'm trying at the moment but then now I'm stuck again and couldn't get out of my box again.  Helpfully someone can give me a hand.

the codes are a bit too long so hopefully by just wordings would work give out an idea what I want.

ok so I'm having a form with let's say radio button of left right up and let's people choose then submit.
I then used the # of votes / sum of votes and input it into pie chart.  I then realized if no one voted for either left/right/up or let's say if one of them isn't being voted YET then I will get an error because the data isn't even in my data.json file.

So if the value/data isn't in data.json YET how can I make the certain option (left/right/up) 0?

Sorry for my bad english but hopefully you can understand what I'm trying to ask.....

here are my codes....of course I skipped posting the body, html tag and stuffs...

in my index.php

```
<form action="store.php" method="post">

<?php

$music_type = array("pop", "rock", "metallic");

foreach($music_type as $type)
{
    echo $type . '<input type="radio" name="type" value='. $type . '>' . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

in my store.php

```
 <?php
 $file_handle = fopen('data.json', 'a');  
 if($file_handle) {                       
    fwrite(                              
      $file_handle,                     
      json_encode($_POST).PHP_EOL       
      );      
   fclose($file_handle);                 
}
else {
   echo 'Error opening data file.';      
}

$file = file('data.json');          // each line gets added to the $file array

$votes = array();                   // initiate $votes to an array

foreach($file as $line)
{
    // json decode current line
    $vote = json_decode($line, true);   

    // use the vote as the key
    $key = $vote['type'];

    // check if current vote exits. If it does increment vote by 1
    if(isset($votes[ $key ]))
    {
        $votes[ $key ]++;
    }   
    // vote doesn't exist yet. Add vote to votes (creates new key). Initiate vote with 1       
    else
    {
        $votes[ $key ] = 1;
    }

}

echo "<h1>Vote Results</h1>";

foreach($votes as $vote => $count)
{
    echo "<b>$vote</b> has $count votes<br />";
}


  $sum = $votes['metallic'] + $votes['pop'] + $votes['rock'];

  $circle_degree = 360;

  $metallic_pie = $votes['metallic'] / $sum * $circle_degree;

  $pop_pie = $votes['pop'] / $sum * $circle_degree;

  $rock_pie = $votes['rock'] / $sum * $circle_degree;
?>

<canvas id="piechart1" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
   piechart("piechart1", ["cyan", "yellow", "green"], [ <?php echo $metallic_pie;?>,
                                                        <?php echo $pop_pie;?>,
                                                        <?php echo $rock_pie;?>]);
</script>
```

and let's say in my data.json only

```
{"type":"rock"}
{"type":"metallic"}
{"type":"metallic"}
```

I know some people say this is not valid json but then I believe from my previous post someone told me because I'm using radio instead of checkbox and so on but my real question is since my json only contains and these
    {"type":"rock"}
    {"type":"metallic"}
exists and NOT 
    {"type":"pop"}
How can I make pop with value of 0.  Without     {"type":"pop"} even exist in data.json php isn't recalling anything inside json.

Hopefully you understand what my question is and again really sorry for my poor explanation and english

Comment: can you dump your code.

Comment: if the option is not selected it wont be posted, how do you handle the json data? you will need somehow to see if the value exists or not, and if it doesnt, set it to 0... share your code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$sum = $votes['metallic'] + $votes['pop'] + $votes['rock'];

$circle_degree = 360;

$metallic_pie = $votes['metallic'] / $sum * $circle_degree;

$pop_pie = $votes['pop'] / $sum * $circle_degree;

$rock_pie = $votes['rock'] / $sum * $circle_degree;
```

To:

```
$voteM = (empty($votes['metallic'])) ? 0 : (int)$votes['metallic'];
$voteP = (empty($votes['pop']))      ? 0 : (int)$votes['pop'];
$voteR = (empty($votes['rock']))     ? 0 : (int)$votes['rock'];
$sum   = $voteM + $voteP + $voteR;

$circle_degree = 360;
$metallic_pie  = $voteM / $sum * $circle_degree;
$pop_pie       = $voteP / $sum * $circle_degree;
$rock_pie      = $voteR / $sum * $circle_degree;
```

Comment: ah really sorry steven.  I used another way instead of the person who taught me in stackoverflow.  I was going to try his way after I'm done with the way I'm using.  Somehow I got stuck again soon after using the codes he suggested and afraid to ask further questions because either I'm lack of knowledge or I'm just not outside of my box to do it right.

Comment: Okay, Looking at your code, you never actually convert the file to `$votes`? Anyway, assuming that you **do** somewhere else.. I'll update my answer to something which will work :)

Comment: omg steven you understand what my question is? :) I somehow couldn't even understand what I want to ask now from the headache haha....

Comment: omg I'm really sorry from the headache and then after reading what you said, I totally missed to post a part of my code.  It's edited now.  Really sorry~!

Comment: this is where my error comes `  $sum = $votes['metallic'] + $votes['pop'] + $votes['rock'];` where the `$votes['pop']` is giving me errors since no one vote for pop yet and it's not even set to 0 yet so I'm getting this unidentified error.

Comment: Haha :P No problem! _Understand_ is probably a stretch! But hopefully the above (edited) answer should fix things :)

Comment: thanks steven.  I'll take a deeper look into your codes and see if that solves what I need and.....really thanks for the help

Comment: As a side note, I just set it up on my _dev_ server and if you just copy/paste/replace the lines I said then it will work except your code won't output `pop has 0 votes` because that is to do with your `foreach($votes as $vote => $count)`... There's a _simple_ fix if you need it to do this?

Comment: thanks thanks a lot ^_^ it works...so first you were setting if those values are empty then give them a default of 0....I thought I need to use something like !exist since it's not in the json file....

Comment: `empty` caters for all _non-values_ (i.e. `0`, `FALSE`, `NULL`, `''`, etc). In your case there is either going to be a value of `>0` or it simply won't exist. You could do a similar thing with `isset` or `is_null` but `empty` is _my_ preferred way to check there is a value in the majority of cases!